# SQLAlchemy sheme that allows two tables to share a primary key column

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, primary-key-design

Say I have two tables, foo and bar. Both have primary keys. I want to set it up in SQLAlchemy so that the combined set of foo.id and bar.id is unique. How would I do that?

I tried adding another table containing only the primary keys and having foreign keys in foo and bar, like so:

```
class foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('primary_keys.id'), primary_key=True) 

class bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('primary_keys.id'), primary_key=True) 

class primary_keys(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'primary_keys'
    id= Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

But it gave me this error:

> FlushError: Instance  has a NULL identity
>   key.  If this is an auto-generated value, check that the database
>   table allows generation of new primary key values, and that the mapped
>   Column object is configured to expect these generated values.  Ensure
>   also that this flush() is not occurring at an inappropriate time, such
>   aswithin a load() event.

Is there maybe a better solution for what I'm trying to do?

EDIT: I'm using a sqlite db.

Comment: Which database is this on? I believe this should work as written with MS-SQL. Also, I assume you're using the [`create_all`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all) function?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using sqlite. And yes I am.

Comment: I believe this should work as coded, perhaps you can provide a fully runnable example that causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you use postgresql or oracle the primary keys of both foo and bar can be defined to use the same sequences.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/defaults.html#defining-sequences

```
table = Table("cartitems", meta,
    Column("cart_id", Integer, Sequence('cart_id_seq'), primary_key=True),
)
```

the sequence object would basically do what you are trying to do with your primary_keys table

Comment: That's interesting, but I'm using sqlite.